# After springboot 3.0 upgrade facing error: Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread when a rest endpoint is called

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-bean, spring-boot-security

I have a Java Rest application written using springboot 2.x. I have upgraded it to java 17 and springboot 3.

The application starts fine after upgrade.
[Application start up success message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTxpr.png)

But when I hit an endpoint using Postman, I get following error :
`threw exception org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.ABCFactory': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

Before the upgrade, the application was working just fine. Everything else remains the same. Can someone help me understand what's wrong here?